# Fullscreen app in OS X with multiple windows?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fullscreen, nswindow, nsapplication

I want to make a fullscreen app that shows the background of the new space, in addition to having normal window behavior. Basically, when the user goes full screen, I want every `NSWindow` in the app to stay the same size, stay in the same position of the screen, but move to the new space. Is this possible? If so, where is the documentation for that kind of behavior?

EDIT: I know this is now quite old, but I have just discovered `customWindowsToEnterFullScreenForWindow`. I have used it to solve the problem. The code is below, just incase anyone else is interested in doing this too.

```
- (NSArray*) customWindowsToEnterFullScreenForWindow:(NSWindow*)window {
    if ([window isEqualTo:self.window]) {
        return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:window, otherwindow, nil];
    }

    return nil;
}

- (NSArray*) customWindowsToExitFullScreenForWindow:(NSWindow*)window {
    if ([window isEqualTo:self.window]) {
        return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:window, otherwindow, nil];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

These are `NSWindowDelegate` methods though, so be sure to set the window's delegate. Otherwise, it may cause some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app can only be on one space at a time. This is a hard limitation. You should file a bug if you want to be able to manage multiple windows on multiple spaces in fullscreen.

Comment: That is not quite what I meant. I want the app to open a new space, but have all of it's windows in that space. It is only supposed to occupy one space at a time.

Comment: If that's the case, then it's already possible, but only if the other windows are panels, not full windows.